# Backbone router.navigate how to pass dynamic ID

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Using backbone marionette I need to navigate to the following route:

```
 'page/:id': 'page'
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
success: function (page) {
  id = page.get('id')
  router.navigate('page', {trigger: true});
}
```

But I have two problems with above.

1) Router is undefined in my view
2) I cannot find a reference to how I pass the ID

How do I resolve this or does marionette have any build in methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the id just putting it in the url:

```
success: function (page) {
   id = page.get('id')
   router.navigate('page/' + id, {trigger: true});
}
```

[Reference](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Router-navigate)

Regarding the router you need to create it:

```
var MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
       'page/:id':     'page'
    },
    page: function(id) {
        ...
    }

});

var router = new MyRouter();
```

Comment: Can we pass an object to a router?